# does every iOS app has it's own single keychain on device?

Tags: ios, iphone, keychain

I'm really confused and hence asking this - does every iOS app has it's own keychain on device(iPhone) or there is only one keychain on device (iPhone) which is used by the different apps ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in Apple docs. For the iPhone, there is only one keychain and apps can store their keychain items in it.

> In iOS, apps have access to a single keychain (which logically
>   encompasses the iCloud keychain). This keychain is automatically
>   unlocked when the user unlocks the device and then locked when the
>   device is locked. An app can access only its own keychain items, or
>   those shared with a group to which the app belongs. It can't manage
>   the keychain container itself.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychains